# Скроллинг контента блока

Tags: jquery

Есть контент, который динамически заливается и формируется. Он расположен  по правую сторону и имеет скролл свой внутренний. Используется плагин perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js (0.6.3), что гуляет в сети. Формирование динамического списка меню (оно заливается через структуру JSON с другого сервера) привело к тому, что скроллер, который визуализируется при создании элемента, тоже не отображается. Он отображается, когда происходит реальное событие мышью или клавой. Т.е позиционируем мышью на блоке и крутим колесо, либо стрелками водим вверх вниз, предварительно опять же спозиционировав, на левом меню.

Сам jquery используется версии: 1.11.3.min.js в моем проекте.

Ссылка на сайт [тут](http://gis.wenorway.ru)

Итак, левое меню формирует свой внутренний рисованный скроллбар при событии скроллинга мыши (на его контенте), либо при движении кнопок вверх/вниз. Просто так он не отображается. Пробовал вызывать программно скроллер мыши по данному компоненту:

В простейшем случае, так:

```
$('.sidemenu_ul').scroll();
```

Но и это не дало результата. В сети написано, что событие скролла

> .scroll() и событие мыши: 
>   wheel

разные по сути, потому это и не срабатывает.

В документации от разработчиков компонента написано, что инициализация и апдейт работает таким образом:

```
  var width = parseInt($("#Width").val());
    var height = parseInt($("#Height").val());

    $("#Demo").width(width).height(height);

    // update scrollbars
    $('#Demo').perfectScrollbar('update');

    // or even with vanilla JS!
    Ps.update(document.getElementById('Demo'));
```

Однако, такой метод не работал и раньше в другом примере меню. Потому проблема скорее всего у разработчика, либо у них не состыковка версий. Короче, запутался с такой казалось бы довольно простой вещью. Потому прошу ответить тех, кто сталкивался с таким плагином по скроллу, и как решить такой баг (от разработчика ли или просто в силу того, что браузер не отвечает, как надо).

Answer (score 1):

Могу посоветовать воспользоваться http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Доступен пример с ajax подгрузкой контента http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/ajax.html

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ!  Я посмотрю данную библиотеку.